# How can I send out email updates from a private Blogger blog when adding new posts?

Tags: blogger, notifications

I am setting up a blog using Blogger that needs to remain private. I understand that a private blog cannot have an RSS feed or use feedburner for email notifications.

I am wondering what other options I have for users to receive an email notification of new posts on the blog. I found a site suggesting that I could set up a Google group and use the email address for the group to send posts out to users, but I tried this and no email was sent out, i.e. I added the email address for the Google group to Settings/Mobile and Email/Email Posts to in Blogger, but the members of the Google group didn't receive an email.

I am wondering if there are other options?

Comment: Did you allow non-group members to send messages to the group?

Comment: I was a group member trying to send a message to the group

Answer (score 2):

The problem can be resolved by following these steps:

1. Go to **Blogger Dashboard > Settings > Mobile and email**
2. Click on "**Add**" in "**Email posts to**" section
3. Mention desired email in the column and click on **Save settings**

Now, every post will reach the mentioned email address. If you want to put more than one email address, separate them with a comma.